# HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error - Broken pipe

Tags: java, mysql, apache, jdbc, glassfish

I'm a beginner to jsp & java.And I have developed a simple web application.
Application is working fine when I deploy on the server for some time.
When I try to run my Web Application after some time server returns the following message:

> HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type - Exception report

message - Internal Server Error

description - The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception-**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 37,611,394 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 37,611,394 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

root cause -

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 37,611,394 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 37,611,394 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

root cause -

java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe

note - The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 logs.
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0
```

(Don't know what went wrong .Still searching Google but no luck yet)

Comment: Can you show us your code, so that we can assess the issue?

Comment: check the database connection .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai)

Answer (score 0):

probably you need to set your connection url to this.

```
jdbcUrl = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourdatabase?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=utf8&autoReconnect=true&verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false
```

Comment: Why would that be needed @Neeson.Z?

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer from its exception `... or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem...`, it seems like it falls into 8 hour timeout issue of MySQL.